# Xcode 9.0 - 3d models not previewing

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, preview, arkit

Xcode is not showing any 3d models preview, does anyone has any idea how to solve this? or do I have to enable some setting?

I have the same issue in two different macs, so I'm guessing that it is some setting I have to activate?..

Please keep in mind this is on of the AR kit samples by apple, not modified.

I should be able to view the model, and be able to rotate it for example.

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js77w.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Please change `Perspective` to `FrontView` and see of the ship is showing or not.

Comment: Just from the one screenshot, there is not enough information to see what your problem really is.

Comment: @iPeter I did that, and still nothing... just to clarify I can see the model when running the app, I can also preview the model by hitting the space bar on file manager, so I believe it is not related to OpenGL.

I've updated xcode to 9.1 today, and still have the same issue, the graph scene does not render any 3D model

Comment: @RuChernChong what information can I provide that will help you figure out the problem?

Comment: I have tried the latest 3 versions of xcode and the beta version as well on both Macs, always uninstalling xcode and reinstalling, will try to update OS to check if it is OS related, I am currently running Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Mac OS Sierra 10.12.06 to Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.1 solved the issue.